# How to connect a Dispatch Queue to a Run Loop?

Tags: objective-c, macos, network-programming

I'm currently in the process of porting my existing Network library to Apple platforms.

The existing implementation uses a single worker thread to process all active connections (objects wrapping raw sockets).  I would like to retain this aspect of the design on Apple platforms.

Instead of using raw sockets, I am using Apple's Network framework.  Connection objects (`nw_connection_t`, `nw_listener_t`, et al.) in this framework expect `dispatch_queue_t` objects - through which event notifications will be sent.  So I have created one of these and pass it to all `nw_...` functions that require it.

My worker thread has retrieved the associated `CFRunLoopRef` instance (or rather created one) by calling `CFRunLoopGetCurrent`, and I'm processing this in my thread's main loop with the following:

```
CFRunLoopRunInMode( kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true );
```

But what I don't understand, and have been unable to figure out, is how I get my dispatch queue to be processed by my thread's RunLoop object?  I'm assuming I need to attach one to the other somehow so that notifications are called at the right time in my worker thread, right?  So, how do I do this?

Comment: Why are you even bothering with a run loop for this dispatch queue? Just give these methods the queue, and you’re done. The whole point of taking a dispatch queue is to get you out of the legacy pattern (that we had to do in the pre-GCD days) of spinning up a thread ourself with its own run loop…

Comment: @Rob Because I already have a thread that manages everything network related.  I have already just given up though and used the main thread, at the expense of having to add more (otherwise unnecessary) synchronisation primitives to my network system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different concepts here. Dispatch Queue is essentially a thread pool, the API of GCD doesn't give contract in regards to which thread it runs its tasks with (with exception to the "main" queue which runs in the "main" thread only), so each separate task of a GCD queue can potentially be executed in a new thread. On the other hand the run loops of Cocoa frameworks are bound to specific thread only (conventionally each thread has only one run loop it was created with).

Long story short: you cannot "connect" a run loop to a dispatch queue, because queues operate in different threads (even if the queues are serial), while a run loop needs a specific thread to work in.

Comment: But the very existence of dispatch_get_main_queue suggests it should be possible to execute a dispatch queue on a specific thread.  I.e., on my thread.  Maybe that's not with a RunLoop, but unless Apple really managed to screw this up too it should be possible, no?

Comment: @James It's definitely possible if you implement your own concurrent API, but not with GCD.

Comment: Urgh.  Ah well, I guess I can't say I'm that surprised.  Everything else about MacOS has been an underwhelming experience to date, so why should this be any different?  :)  Thanks.

Comment: @James `NSOperationQueue` API is much more flexible in this case, since custom operation classes can have any implementation under the hood. E.g. [here](https://gist.github.com/TheDreamsWind/49bc1d11817828d627d3968364b08d5e) you can find a custom queue implemented on top of a POSIX thread, so you can potentially use your worker thread instead and dispatch your tasks in the thread's run loop

Comment: No offense, for the sake of interacting with the Network framework, I think you’re just digging a deeper hole introducing operation queues…